# RAID 6 >80% Highest Active Time with small I/O

Tags: raid, storage, raid5

I have a RAID 6 with 18 disks. It is used as a storage for small images(5-500Kb). It is about 6TB full of data. I have an utility that reads that images to the ram and then send it over network. I noticed that with about 10Mb/s I/O I have about 100% active time. qlen is about 18-25, iops is about 500-700. is it because of a lot small requests? Can I improve that? I noticed that it could affect other applications that use that storage for their needs. Also, response time for some files can grow till 700-1000ms.

Comment: Just out of interest what size disks are you using?

Comment: Do you have a hardware RAID controller? Do you have read or write cache? What types of disks are installed?

Comment: Are you only reading from the array, or there is any write activity?

Comment: ARECA (X86-64-STORPORT) SAS RAID Host Adapter (RAID6-ENGINE Inside), 17 drives by 384Gb. I made a mistake, we have raid 6. sorry. There is a lot of write activity too. But the summary i/o is not higher than 5-10Mb/s. Models of hdd I'll send later. I do not have an access to it yet. I use Windows system cache to cache that i/o. There is an util Cacheset that allows to set a value for it. I use about 10Gb of RAM for it.

Comment: ewwhite, if you talk not about windows cache, please, point it out. I can check it. I've just encountered that problem, so not have enough information. At first I would be even glad to here a direction where I can look at

Comment: about cache.. that util does not hit cache, because work with a file only once. Steps: 1) read file 2) send file 3) remove file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't directly answer your question, because drive performance has a whole lot of 'it depends'. It depends a lot on IO types, IO sizing, cache, controllers etc.

Most especially, you need to understand the difference in 'cost' of read vs. write IO.

Write IO is expensive on a RAID 6 - each IO requires 6 disk operations. That means you can just divide your number of spindles by 6 for sustained transfer. There are a few tricks you can do to hide this problem - you can cache aggressively, because if you're able to stripe coalesce, you massively reduce that problem. If you write *one* block, you need to do 6 operations each. However if you can write a full stripe, you have to just write an extra 2 blocks, making it more efficient than RAID 1 would be. You can also defer a write, and just send it down to disk later - causing the write to complete at 'cache speed' until you fill your cache.

Read IO on the other hand - takes one operation to service, but it *must* be done real time - you can't defer it like you can writes. That means your reads are generally slower - but again, you can partially mitigate this by caching - but you do have to exploit likely patterns of reads (e.g. large sequentials, re-read of common files).

That means there's practically speaking a very large difference between theoretical and optimal performance based on workload, which is why this sort of question is so difficult to answer.

In your case - you say you have small IOPs. 500-700 IOPs for 10MB/sec means you've got small IOs. So you could quite easily - if they're a random pattern - running at the worst case speed of your disks. Either because your read IOs are random and can't be cached, or your write IOs are random and thus can't be coalesced and full-striped to disk - as soon as your write cache fills, you'll slow down to 'disk' speed, and that can be abominably slow. (18 disks gives you effective 3 spindles in that scenario - you're getting more than that though)

I *think* you'll *probably* be ok on controller to disk ratios, but it's hard to say. It's *usually* the case that the limiting factor is the spinning rust, as that's generally the slowest part of the system. But we get distorted expectations thanks to huge caches and effective caching algorithm.

So I would suggest that what you need to check - what sort of ratio of IO you get. (Ignore MB/sec, it's clear you're not even getting close to theoretical levels there). Check cache hit ratios and cache sizing - if you can, look at how full your caches are and what rate of full stripe write you're getting (if you're doing much write IO).

Also check disk seek rate - see how often your heads are moving around on the disks -  again, one of the downsides of intensive random read patterns is your disks will be thrashing.